# How do I decode the schema id from avro event in Kafka wire format?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro

Hope you all doing well.

I'm ingesting data from a Kafka topic where I have multiple event types and schemas for each type. As Kafka is using [wire format](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#wire-format), the first byte is the magic byte, from byte 1 to 4 we have the schema-id and after the 5th byte we have the data itself.

I want to decode the schema-id so I'll be able to get the schema from schema-registry. How can I do that with Python?

For example, if I have `b'\x00\x00\x00\x04'` as the schema-id binary, how can I decode this binary so I can get the actual value of the schema-id?

Comment: You want to get the schema manually instead of letting the consumer deserializer do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the full five byte header, you should be able to do the following:

```py
from struct import unpack
magic, schema_id = unpack('>bI', header_bytes)
```

This was taken from the way that the `confluent-kafka-python` library grabs the `schema_id`: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/e671bccb8a4f98302748ccf60d5d579f68c6613d/src/confluent_kafka/schema_registry/avro.py#L315

Comment: It Worked for me! Thanks a lot, Scott!

Comment: Maybe you know how can I do that by using confluent-kafka-python library?
Message.headers() gives me tuple of (k, v), there is no header bytes information.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I have not used that library.